# A port that is ostensibly USB looks unusual

Tags: usb

The side of my HP Elitebook 840 G2 has two USB ports. The users' guide states that they are both USB 3.0 ports and no information is offered to suggest they are different from each other, yet there is a physical difference.

[image: pic]
[image]
The port on the left will accept a USB device. I am unable to plug a USB device into the USB port on the right. I looked at Wikipedia's diagrams for USB ports but did not locate a diagram that matches the port on the right.

How can I use the port on the right?

Comment: Can you get us a picture a little bit lower down? It almost looks like a USB male, though I can't see how you'd be expected to use it like that.

Comment: ... but a USB male has a plastic thing inside. I will update if I get a chance to take another photo.

Comment: The one on the left looks damaged to me.

Comment: The one on the left works. It's not damaged. The perspective lets you see more of the plastic walls.

Comment: Need a better image with light pointed in the ports.

Comment: As you mentioned in your answer, it simply looked a bit bent/out of place to me. You can mark your answer as best answer. Good job.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Both USB male and USB female have plastic things inside, they hold the pins that connect to eachother. The reason I thought it looked like a USB male was the size looks smaller, and the plastic thing looks closer to the top. Though maybe I'm just seeing things, as these images aren't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the attempted answers. I got tweezers and pulled the metal rectangle out. It now will accept a USB device.

Answer (score 0):

According to HP's [specifications](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c04552057#AbT1), your laptop has three regular USB 3.0 ports and one USB 3.0 charging port.

[image]

[image]

If this port is the odd one out, I would assume that it is the USB 3.0 charging port. Is the port highlighted in the above image in the same location as your different port, on the left side of the laptop?

USB 3.0 charging ports are able to continue to provide 5V of charging voltage even when the computer is turned off, to allow them to charge another device at all times. On laptops, USB 3.0 charge ports are only enabled when the laptop is connected to its AC adapter, to prevent them from draining the laptop's own battery.

**Edit:**

Now that we know it's a USB port on the right side of the laptop, it *should* in theory be a regular USB 3.0 port.

[image]

Comment: The USB charging port has a different logo. The charging port is on the left side of the computer. My problem is on the right side of the computer where both USB ports have the same USB logo.

Comment: This isn't by design; there is something physically wrong with the port. It is supposed to be physically identical to the port next to it. It's either been damaged and/or attempted to be repaired by someone else or perhaps it came from the factory with a defect. What's the history of the device? Did you buy it second hand?

Comment: I bought it used, online.

Comment: @H2ONaCl You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment